# How to slide a responsive SVG slider?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, responsive

I have made this SVG slider.

When hovering over the red bars at the bottom the rainbow **rectangle** `#moveSVG` should **slide** from right to left or vice versa. 
That works fine, but only if I don't make the `#moveSVG` responsive.

When I make the SVG **responsive** by..

- .. removing the `width` and `height` and setting it with css `100vw` and `100vh`
- .. adding `viewBox="0 0 5200 900" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax
  slice"`

..it doesn't work anymore. The rectangle is sliced of.
(See snippet)

---

**Now how can I make this responsive slider without slicing it?**

P.S. There are 2 solutions which I would prefer not to use:

1. instead of moving by setting `transform` to `translate`, I can change the `viewBox` x coordinate, but that seems sloppy since I don't have to change the y width and height
2. I can use the `transform` on the sub-SVG #bandsSVG, but in the real project there are 3 sub-SVGs so I would have to do it 3 times. Also seems sloppy.

**Code --> https://jsfiddle.net/e_motiv/53w0unc3/**

Comment: Could you also include the snippet without the responsive modifications to let us see how it functions?

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning. Why is `setAttribute("viewBox", totalTransform + " 0 5200 900"` more "sloppy" than `setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + totalTransform + ",0)")`?

Comment: I found the solution meanwhile. Sorry, I didn't think I would find it. I will post it as my own answer.
ccprog, I know, it's perfectionism, but well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is actually to add a group below the svg and translate that group and leave the svg with responsiveness and viewBox.

```
<g id="realMoveSGV">..</g>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e_motiv/xv93zdx1/